# Generate a report from oracle forms into RTF format

Tags: oraclereports

I have a report that I called from *Oracle Forms 6i*. My issue is that when I run the report directly from *Oracle Forms*, it does not generate output file. I want to generate the report directly into a *RTF* format.

Below is the code I used to call and generate the report from *Oracle forms* (trigger `WHEN_BUTTON_PRESSED`):

```
/* Formatted on 2008/11/01 12:59 (Formatter Plus v4.8.0) */
DECLARE

   v_org_id         NUMBER;
   l_res_create     NUMBER;
   v_cust_num       VARCHAR2(10);
   v_err            NUMBER;

BEGIN

    v_org_id := Fnd_Profile.VALUE ('ORG_ID');
    v_err := 0;

   BEGIN
   SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM
     INTO v_cust_num
     FROM xx_org_parties
where header_id = :XXPARTYDET.HEADER_ID;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         Fnd_Message.set_string ('Customer Not Created');
         Fnd_Message.show;
         RAISE form_trigger_failure;
         v_err := 1;
   END;


  --------------------------------------------------------
    BEGIN
      IF v_err = 0
      THEN
         l_res_create :=
            Fnd_Request.submit_request ('XXNIR',
                                        'XX_WELCOME_LTR',
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        FALSE,
                                        v_org_id,
                                        v_cust_num,
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0),
                                        CHR (0)
                                       );
                                        --, 
         --CHR(0));
         :SYSTEM.message_level := 25;
         COMMIT_FORM;



         Fnd_Message.DEBUG (   'Your request # '
                            || l_res_create
                            || ' has submitted'
                           );   

        :parameter.P_REQUEST_ID:=  l_res_create;

          END IF;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         Fnd_Message.DEBUG ('Error ' || SQLCODE || ',' || SQLERRM);
       --  exit;
   END; 
   END;
```

Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks,
Shashikant